# The object does not support property or method "attachEvent"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using IE, everything was good till I check all boxes of "delete browsing history" as shown below:

[image]

this part of code where I got the error

```
function CloseCtrlLanceurApplication() {
var programLauncher = document.getElementById('ctrlLanceurApplication');
if (programLauncher) programLauncher.Terminate();
}
window.attachEvent('onunload', CloseCtrlLanceurApplication);
if (!document.getElementById('ctrlLanceurApplication')) {alert('WARNING: external application launch component of executable type not installed on the client machine');}<
```

Then when I open my application again, I got this error `The object does not support property or method "attachEvent"`

Comment: The dialog is not useful to track down your problem, you need to show the relevant part of your code where the error occures.

Comment: hello @t.niese thanks for answer, I updated my question, I didnt put the code, coz it was worked, just after deleting my browsing history then I got this problem

Comment: `attachEvent` is a non standard deprecated function. You probably had the compatibility mode in IE active for your application which made `attachEvent` available, and by deleting the history you might have reset the settings compatibility mode. Anyway you have to update your code to use standard conform functions, and only if you really have to support old IE version you need to create fallback.

Comment: Thank you @t.niese problem resolved, I couldnt change the code so I fallback then my page works well

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you also erased you site preferences for compatibilities mode too.

To prevent compatibility issues adding event, you should use some sort of basic browser sniffing (feature-based), and then apply the appropiate attach event function (for backward compatibility of older versions of Internet Explorer):

```
// Modern browsers
if(typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') {
    window.addEventListener('load', CloseCtrlLanceurApplication, false);
}

// Internet Explorer
else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', CloseCtrlLanceurApplication);
}
```